# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_36_input to have shape (None, 12) but got array with shape (140, 2)

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras

**Create model:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim = 12, units = 10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units = 8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))

print('Training the model...')
```

**Compile model:**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

while running the `model.fit()`

**Fit the model:**

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_36_input to have shape 
(None, 12) but got array with shape (140, 2)
```

Comment: Your data has a shape of `(140, 2 )` instead of `2` we require `12 ` here. Reshape your data with `numpy.reshape`

Answer (score 0):

**Input dimension means the number of features or columns that your input is supposed to have.**

The neural network will try to adjust to this input shape.
In your case, you have specified `input_dim = 12`, but in your data (140,2) there are only 2 features or columns.

**So there are two options:**

1. Set `input_dim =2`
2. Reshape the input array to be in multiples of specified input dimension i.e. 12.

**In your case, ONLY option 1 works because (140,2) cannot be reshaped into multiples of 12.**

Note: other valid `input_dim` for you could be 14 (reshape input to (20,14)), 10 (reshape input to (28,10))